# How to sort an associative array and retain the keys?

Tags: bash, sort, array

I have an array with filenames as keys and a numerical value as values.

```
MYARRAY[00001.jpg] = 31
MYARRAY[00002.jpg] = 200
MYARRAY[00003.jpg] = 98
```

I need to sort them so they are ordered by value.
Which I am doing with

```
IFS=$'\n' SORTED=($(sort <<<"${MYARRAY[*]}"))
```

However I lose the keys and just have numerical ones now.

Desired output would be

```
00001.jpg:31
00003.jpg:98
00002.jpg:200
```

How can I retain the keys in such a sort?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your keys don't contain colons or newlines and your values don't contain newlines:

```
for key in "${!MYARRAY[@]}"; do
  printf '%s:%s\n' "$key" "${MYARRAY[$key]}"
done | sort -t : -k 2n
```

If you need to arrange the key in the order given by the values, read back the output:

```
IFS=$'\n'; set -f
sorted_keys=($(
    for key in "${!MYARRAY[@]}"; do
      printf '%s:%s\n' "$key" "${MYARRAY[$key]}"
    done | sort -t : -k 2n | sed 's/:.*//'))
unset IFS; set +f
```

Comment: I can't seem to get useful output with this so far. Could you humour me a bit. What does the sed stuff do?

Comment: @dibs The for loop prints out lines like `00001.jpg:31`. The sed command removes the part after the colon. I fixed an error that caused `sorted_keys` to be a single string containing all the names, instead of an array as intended.

Comment: How would I modify this function to display for example only the TOP 2 file names, without the count?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Hello, could you kindly explain what the `-k 2n` option means? Best wishes, von Spotz

Comment: @vonspotz `-k` sets the sort key, i.e. what part of each line to use to sort. `2` means to start at the second field. `n` means to use numerical order rather than lexicographic order (so `9` sorts before `10`).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you very much!